# Open a File with Desktop Application with Applet

Tags: java, applet

somehow I want to open a file form a web application with the desktop application from client side.

My boss told me to use **Applet**. I've been through all the internet could provide me, but still can't find how to do it.

I've build a code program from java class to open the file directly but I can't make the applet running from JSP file.

Here's my code :

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
      try {
  URI uri = new URI("your/local/file/path");
  Desktop desktop = null;
  if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  }

  if (desktop != null)
    desktop.browse(uri);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException use) {
  use.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

If somebody ever done it before, I'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Applets do not have access to the local file system due to security issues. However, there are ways to grant file system access to applets. This article describes the procedure: https://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm. Altough I have not tested it myself and it is rather old, the article seems promising. I hope, this helps you.

Comment: I've follow the steps, it works to make a signed applet. But still my applet method not working. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Seems like there have been some changes since. I think, the key term is previledged code, as explained here: https://javapapers.com/core-java/is-your-java-code-privileged/

Comment: I found the answer, just need to signed the applet. I found the key while surfing on the forum and find this one 

If you are using Netbeans then right click on your Applet project ->Properties->webstart-> clickon Enablewebstart ->customize->select radio self-signedby generatedkey->ok

Hope when somenone facing this problem, can be fixed with this. Thanks